# Where can I find the meaning of clang return codes?

Tags: c, clang

I can't find documentation for exit codes in clang.

I haven't been able to find it in the official [Clang Compiler User's Manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html)

Important note: this question is about the clang compiler. I'm NOT asking about MSVC which is a different compiler.

Comment: Could you provide the link of the project?

Comment: OK. Maybe I was a bit hasty with that duplicate closure. Can you clarify with what system/platform you are using?

Comment: This question is not about solving any issue. System/platform is irrelevant. Specific project is irrelevant. What I'm asking is were can I find the documentation for clang return codes as I can't find it in the official webpage.  This question is NOT about MSVC; it's about clang. I will edit my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: But, if that error code is a *system* value, then it will be the same for MSVC and clang if running on Windows.

Comment: @AdrianMole "if that error code is a system value" is it? Does clang return system values? Where can I find that info in the documentation?

Comment: I'm only getting exit code 0 for success and 1 for failure (tried file not found, syntax error and unknown command line option). This is pretty common for command line utilities. Maybe that's all there is to it. Have you observed any other codes?

Comment: You have [edit]ed your question, clarifying some bits. That's great,, thanks! But you removed the relevant error message. Would you mind to add it again, please? -- And while you're at it, please add which tool reports that error, which OS this runs on, the specific command line that calls Clang, and any other error output between the call and the final error message. Perhaps this is an uncaught exception with an actual system-dependent error code.

Comment: @thebusybee I removed all that info because it wasn't relevant. It caused confusion and people started asking about the conditions that caused the specific error message. But it was just an example, my question wasn't about that specific error message.

Comment: As we see from the accepted answer, the error messages before the final one _are relevant_ because they tell you the specific tool that reported the error. Such messages will give a hint on the underlying reason. In my experience the specific number is not important, only zero means "OK". The error messages are important.

Comment: @thebusybee Could be relevant for another question, but this question is not about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the exit codes from `clang` are not documented.

So, I tried to figure it out from the source.  The `main` for `clang` is
in a generated file called
`build/tools/clang/tools/driver/clang-driver.cpp`, which is created from
[`llvm/cmake/modules/llvm-driver-template.cpp.in`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/llvm/cmake/modules/llvm-driver-template.cpp.in).
That calls `clang_main` in
[`clang/tools/driver/driver.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang/tools/driver/driver.cpp).

Within `driver.cpp`, the only manifest exit codes are 0 for success and
1 for error.  So, for most purposes, that is the answer: 0 or 1.

- Example of 0: Give `clang` normal input.
- Example of 1: Give `clang` input with a syntax error, or command line
  error, etc.

However, if a program executed by the `clang` driver exits non-zero,
such as `ld` when linking, then `clang` will relay that code.
Consequently, you can get any exit code at all from `clang`, depending
on what the programs it runs do.  If you're seeing diverse codes, this
is probably why.  Add `-v` to the `clang` command line to see the exact
command lines it is running to track down the origin of mysterious exit
codes.

- Example of 42: Create your own `ld` that does `exit 42` and stick it
  in the front of the `PATH`.

If `clang` crashes or fails an assertion, then the consequences are
system-specific; on Linux, this results in the process dying by a
signal, which the shell will typically map to an exit code greater than
128.  However, in most cases, the process that crashes is one invoked by
the `clang` driver.  The driver then detects a crashing sub-process, and
reports that using exit code 1.

- Example of crash: Feed `clang` input from a crash report, for example
  [issue 65153](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/65153).

Finally, there's a somewhat weird case: if `clang` receives `SIGPIPE`,
then it exits with code `EX_IOERR` from `sysexits.h`, which on my Linux
system is 74.  There is also a `#define EX_IOERR 74` in
[`llvm/Support/ExitCodes.h`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/llvm/include/llvm/Support/ExitCodes.h)
for systems (like Windows) that do not have `sysexits.h`.

- Example of 74: Run `clang -E` (preprocess) on a large file, pipe the
  output into `head`, then `echo $PIPESTATUS`.

It's possible there are other cases I missed, as the above was
discovered mainly by manually tracing backward from `clang_main`, and
there are a lot of backward paths.  But I think this is at least close
to comprehensive.